# visual basic inserting into multiple tables on one mysql database

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-express

hello I wanted to know if it is possible to get one click on a button to send the same data to one database but multiple tables. because in my current situation i only get the data in to the first of the two. here is the entire code of said button:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        MsgBox("Meld enige gebreken bij je leraar samen de naam van de computer (deze staat op de stikker die op het apparaat te vinden is)")

    Dim myHost As String = Dns.GetHostName
    Dim ipEntry As IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(myHost)
    Dim ip As String = ""
    Dim nee As String
    Dim user As String
    nee = "nee"

    dbconn = New MySqlConnection("Data Source=172.17.80.153;user id=connectinguser;password=123456;database=vbtest;")
    Try
        dbconn.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error in connection, please check Database and connection server.")
    End Try

    For Each tmpIpAddress As IPAddress In ipEntry.AddressList
        If tmpIpAddress.AddressFamily = Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then
            Dim ipAddress As String = tmpIpAddress.ToString
            ip = ipAddress
            Exit For
        End If
    Next



    If ip = "" Then
        Throw New Exception("No 10. IP found!")
    End If

    If TypeOf My.User.CurrentPrincipal Is System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal Then
        ' The application is using Windows authentication.
        ' The name format is DOMAIN\USERNAME.
        Dim parts() As String = Split(My.User.Name, "\")
        Dim username As String = parts(1)

        Dim uname As String = My.User.Name

        uname = uname.Remove(0, 10)
        user = uname

    End If

    sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_nee(Gebruikersnaam,Computernaam,IPAddress, Keuze) VALUES('" & user & "', '" & My.Computer.Name & "', '" & ip & "', '" & nee & "' )"

    sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_alles(Gebruikersnaam,Computernaam,IPAddress, Keuze) VALUES('" & user & "', '" & My.Computer.Name & "', '" & ip & "', '" & nee & "' )"



    Try
        dbcomm = New MySqlCommand(sql, dbconn)
        dbread = dbcomm.ExecuteReader()
        dbread.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error in saving to Database. Error is :" & ex.Message)
        dbread.Close()
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

it is a bit messy but i'm not a good coder so it just all kinds of things that is found to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim sql1 As String = ""
Dim sql2 As String = ""

sql1 = "INSERT INTO tbl_nee(Gebruikersnaam,Computernaam,IPAddress, Keuze) VALUES('" & user & "', '" & My.Computer.Name & "', '" & ip & "', '" & nee & "' )"

sql2 = "INSERT INTO tbl_alles(Gebruikersnaam,Computernaam,IPAddress, Keuze) VALUES('" & user & "', '" & My.Computer.Name & "', '" & ip & "', '" & nee & "' )"

Dim sql = String.Concat(sql1, ";", sql2)


    Try
        dbcomm = New MySqlCommand(sql, dbconn)
        dbread = dbcomm.ExecuteReader()
        dbread.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error in saving to Database. Error is :" & ex.Message)
        dbread.Close()
        Exit Sub
    End Try
```

Comment: thanks, but how can i delclare them now? just with dim sql1 as string and dim sql2 as string? of with more? because it is still not working for me.

Comment: Paste error code here. I wan't to see what kind of error you get.

Comment: im getting these errors about the ";"
Dim sql1 As String = ""; <- character not valid
Dim sql2 As String = ""; <- same as above

Comment: Sorry, i've put semicolon on the end of declarations. It is habbit from C-like languages. Remove that semicolon and try again. It should work.

Comment: It did not work it gave no errors but it did not add to the tbl_alles

Comment: Put breakpoint on line dbcomm = New MySqlCommand(sql, dbconn) and then check what is under sql variable in that line. You should see complete insert statement with values that should be stored in table. Also check connection string.

Comment: i have a breakdown but how can i see what the sql variable is? and the connection string? i have never before worked with visual studio express

Comment: Than you have to take some tutorials. Try with this one http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3rOT-H_3WGQ

Comment: for some reason it just worked from one moment to another (with the code you gave me) so thanks for the help and i will look in to the video for when i need it again